# Is there a way to base a parent's width on the child, but keep that width fixed as the child changes?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Example: a button that toggles to a larger font on click

In this case, I want the button width based on the initial text width, but to keep a constant size if the child width grows when the button is hovered.

```
<button
  className={styles.button}
>
  <span>hello</span>
</button>
```

```
.button {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
  padding: 10px;

  &:hover {
    font-family: 'OpenSans-ExtraBold';
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below. You duplicate the text, you make one of them having the bold font (I am using font-size instead) that will define the width then you update the other one on hover. Since the bigger text will define the dimension the smaller one will have no overflow issue.

```css
.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
}

.button:hover,
.button span::before{
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button span::before,
.button span::after {
 content:attr(data-text);
}

.button span::before {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.button span::after {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <span data-text="hello"></span>
</button>
```

Also like below if you want the small text to define the dimension (pay attention to overflow)

```css
.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
}

.button:hover span::after{
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button span::before,
.button span::after {
 content:attr(data-text);
}

.button span::before {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.button span::after {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <span data-text="hello"></span>
</button>
```